# Problem with mailer plugin

Tags: emails

My problem is that the [Mailer](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-Mailer/) plugin (version 0.5) does not work with Craft Pro 2.3.2620. Unfortunately, I get no error message - it still does not send e-mail (the log is empty). Craft in general is able to send e-mails.

Has someone else the same problem?

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developer? https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-Mailer/issues

Answer (score 2):

While this question is a bit old, for the sake of completeness I'll echo what Brad mentioned in the comment above.

Plugin bugs are best handled by notifying the developer directly. This plugin happens to be on Github and it appears that the developer has responded to all open [issues](https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-Mailer/issues) and closed them out.

Additionally, the convention for tagging Stack Exchange posts that are related to plugins is to prefix the plugin's name with the word `plugin`. In this case, a good tag may be `plugin-craftmailer` or `plugin-mailer`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this plugin wasn't working due to a custom submit button being used in the CP. It has been fixed in the current version. https://github.com/victor-in/Craft-Mailer